# Handling of new Calendar/Date Instances for every Row of a ResultSet

Tags: java, date, calendar, instance, resultset

I want to get the day of the week for a number of dates saved in a database.

```
try {
        ResultSet rs = DBHelper.st.executeQuery("SELECT date FROM days ORDER BY date ASC;");
        while (rs.next()) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(rs.getString(1)));
            String d = new SimpleDateFormat("EE").format(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
            System.out.println(d + ", " rs.getString(1).substring(8));
        }
    } catch(SQLException xc) {xc.printStackTrace();}
```

I am generating a new Calendar Instance for every row of the ResultSet but somehow the weekday parsed is the same for every date.
The Calendar always gives back the day of the week which matches the first date in the list.

e.g.

```
Tue, 05 | 
Tue, 06
...
```

I am guessing that the Calendar Instance stays the same for all rows.
Can someone suggest a way to make sure that Calendar c is updated for every row? My approach does not seem to cut it.

Comment: Why do you think 1) that you need a `Calendar`, and 2) that `new SimpleDateFormat("EE").format(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))` is the right thing to do?! Your problem can be easily solved by retrieving the value as a `java.sql.Date` and then formatting once using a single format.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am open to better suggestions...

Comment: What Java version are you on? Asking because Java 8 and later offer some better options compared to Java 6 and 7.

Comment: @OleV.V. Im running Java 8 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    DateTimeFormatter dayFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE, dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        ResultSet rs = DBHelper.st.executeQuery("SELECT date FROM days ORDER BY date ASC;");
        while (rs.next()) {
            LocalDate date = rs.getObject(1, LocalDate.class);
            System.out.println(date.format(dayFormatter));
        }
    } catch (SQLException xc) {
        xc.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With Java 8 and a modern JDBC driver (JDBC 4.2 or higher) you should be able to get a `LocalDate` object directly from your result set. `LocalDate` is one of the classes of `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

The `Calendar` class is long outdated, and `SimpleDateFormat` is not only that, it is also notoriously troublesome. I recommend you avoid those classes completely.

PS Remember to close your result set when you’re done with it. Or use a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

If someone reading along is using Java 6 or 7, the following changes will be necessary: Add ThreeTen Backport to your project (link below). Get a `java.sql.Date` from the result set using its `getDate` method. Convert it to a `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate` using `DateTimeUtils.toLocalDate`. Also import `DateTimeFormatter` from `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter`.

### What went wrong in your code?

`c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)` returns a code for the day of week, an `int` in the interval from 1 (Sunday) through 7 (Saturday). When you pass this number to `SimpleDateFormat.format(Object)`, it is interpreted as a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch of January 1, 1970 at 0:00 UTC. So very few milliseconds into that day. It was a Thursday, I got `Thu` as output from your code, I would expect you got the same if you’re in Europe/Berlin time zone or in UTC. For time zones west of UTC it was still Wednesday, and the output would be `Wed`. I cannot explain how you got `Tue`, and I have not been able to reproduce this.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer by Ole V.V. is correct and should be accepted.

## `DayOfWeek`

Also, it sounds like you may be trying to derive a distinct list of day-of-week values touched by one or more of your dates returned in the result set.

If so, define a `Set` to hold `DayOfWeek` objects. A `Set` by definition eliminates duplicates. So if you add `DayOfWeek.MONDAY` three times, you end up with only one in the set.

An `EnumSet` is an implementation of `Set` optimizes to hold `Enum` objects.

```
Set< DayOfWeek > dows = EnumSet.noneOf( DayOfWeek.class ) ;
```

In that code sample seen in the Answer by Ole V.V., after obtaining the `LocalDate` object named `date`, get its day-of-week and add to our set.

```
DayOfWeek dow = date.getDayOfWeek() ;
dows.add( dow ) ;
```